# How do I webscrape tables onto two different Sheets on the Excel Spreadsheet?

Tags: python, excel, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, playwright-python

This is my code that webscrapes the table from these two links. It doesn't crash.
"https://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/English/Jockey/JockeyRanking.aspx"
"https://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/English/Trainers/TrainerRanking.aspx"

However, when I run it, the two tables seem to overlap each other and print on the same sheet rather than different sheets. Is there a way to fix this?

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

def scrape_ranking(url, sheet_name):
    with sync_playwright() as pw:
        browser = pw.chromium.launch()
        page = browser.new_page()
        page.goto(url, wait_until="networkidle")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content(), "html.parser")
        table = soup.select_one(".table_bd")

        if table is None:
            print("Table not found.")
        else:
            df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
            df.to_excel("hkjc.xlsx", sheet_name=sheet_name, index=True)

# Scrape TrainerRanking page
url_trainer = "https://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/English/Trainers/TrainerRanking.aspx"
scrape_ranking(url_trainer, "TrainerRanking")

# Scrape JockeyRanking page
url_jockey = "https://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/English/Jockey/JockeyRanking.aspx"
scrape_ranking(url_jockey, "JockeyRanking")

print("done")
```

Comment: Is that same sheet `JockeyRanking`? Do the dfs really get combined or does only the last one remain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`ExcelWriter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html#pandas.ExcelWriter) on append mode:

```py
            df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
            with pd.ExcelWriter("hkjc.xlsx", 
                                engine="openpyxl", 
                                mode='a', if_sheet_exists='new') as writer:
                df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=True)
```

If you use `if_sheet_exists='replace'`, it will over-write if there's already a `sheet_name` sheet; `if_sheet_exists='overlay'` will add rows in such a case.

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly! ExcelWriter seems really useful! I'll try and learn how to use it

Comment: @NicholasChan glad to help! I was delighted to discover it myself - quite recently as well